# Two consecutive continua

Tags: gn.general-topology

Are  there  two non homeomorphic  continua  $X,Y$  such that  $X $  can  be  embedded in $Y$  **but  there is  no**  topological  space  $Z$  with $$X<Z<Y.$$

The  later  relation means  that  $Z$ is    homeomorphic  neither  to  $X$  nor  to  $Y$  but  $Z$  contains  a  copy  of  $X$ and  can  be  embedded  in $Y$.

What  about  if  we remove  the  metrizability conditions  but save  the  Hausdorff condition?

Comment: @Ben Thank you very  much  for  your  revision.

Comment: So to be clear, you do not require $Z$ to be a continuum?

Comment: @NateEldredge   Yes, we require.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really allow $Z$ to be any topological space, then no such example exists.  If $X$ embeds as a proper subset of $Y$, then for any $y \in Y \setminus X$, we have open neighborhoods separating $X$ and $y$ (since $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff).  So if we let $Z = X \cup \{y\}$, then the inclusion of $X$ into $Z$ is an embedding.  And clearly $Z$ is not homeomorphic to $X$ or $Y$ because it is not connected.

If you meant to require $Z$ to be a continuum, then an example is given by  $X = [0,1]$ and $Y = S^1$. If $Z$ can be properly embedded in $Y = S^1$, then the embedding must miss at least one point of $Y$, so in fact $Z$ embeds in $(0,1)$.  The only compact connected subsets of $(0,1)$ are closed intervals, hence homeomorphic either to $[0,1]$ or a point or empty.  So if $X = [0,1]$ embeds in $Z$, then $Z$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

None of this requires assuming metrizability.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  interesting answer. According to your  answer, we obtain the  following consecutive sequence :$\{ pt\} < [0,1] < S^{1}<....$. How  can we  continue this  sequence? Is there   another  consecutive  sequence  $\{pt\}<X<Y<..$  But  $X$ is not  homeomorphic to the interval?