# Is the pair $(C([0 \;1]),\mathbb{C})$ a consecutive pair?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Motivated [by this  post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259251/a-consecutive-resolution-of-continum-algebras-to-a-simple-continum-algebra) we  give  the  following  definition:

**Definition:** A  pair  of unital rings $(R,S)$  is  called  a  consecutive pair of  rings if they do not  have  non trivial idempotent and  satisfy the following two  conditions:

1)There  is  a  surjective  morphism $\phi:R\to  S$.

2)If a unital  ring $W$ without  non trivial idempotent  possess a surjective  sequence  of  morphisms $R\to W \to S$  then either $W\simeq R$  or $W \simeq  S$.

Let $C([0,1])$  be  the  ring of  all complex continuous functions.

> Is the pair $(C([0,1]), \mathbb{C})$ a  consecutive  pair of  rings?

Comment: It is perhaps worth highlighting, for others reading this, that condition (2) does not assume any topology or continuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to the question [prime ideals in C([0,1])](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35793/prime-ideals-in-c0-1) explain why the answer is no, assuming that Yemon Choi was mistaken in his answer in believing that you are only interesting in continuous homomorphims.

In particular it is explained that there are non-maximal prime ideals in the ring $C([0,1])$. Given such a prime $P$, $C([0,1])/P$ will provide a non-trivial $W$.

Comment: Nice! I forgot that the simplest way to ensure no non-trivial idempotents is to be an integral domain...

Comment: @SimonWadsley  Thank you very  much  for  your  very elegant answer.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** the following answer was based on the assumption that $W$ is Banach and the ring morphisms $R\to W\to {\mathbb C}$ were continuous. My apologies for misunderstanding the question.

---

I think the answer is yes, because $W$ must be isomorphic to $C(K)$ for some closed subset $K\subset [0,1]$. The condition about idempotents implies $K$ is connected. The only connected subsets of $[0,1]$ are closed sub-intervals, and these are either homeo to $[0,1]$ itself or are degenerate singletons.

Comment: R is just a ring not necessarily a c* algebra

Comment: You mean $W$, right? I assumed you were only interested in continuous algebra homomorphisms, and then every closed ideal in $C(X)$ is given by the functions vanishing on some open subset $U$

Comment: Is it obvious that the  kernel  of $C([0 1]) \to W$ is closed?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Well that is why I was assuming you were working with continuous homomorphisms. I agree that in general it is not obvious if a homomorphism defined on $C([0,1])$ is continuous (the Dales-Esterle counterexamples to Kaplansky's question) but in the present case we may be able to say more. Let me think about this; I retract my earlier comment on your original question.