# A minimal continuum

Tags: gn.general-topology, continuum-theory

A continuum $X$ is called *minimal* if it is not a single point and is homeomorphic to all its nontrivial subcontinua.
Here a trivial continuum is a single point.

> What is an example of a minimal continuum not homeomorphic to the interval?

This question is motivated by the following post and its related linked questions.

[Two consecutive continua](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259017/two-consecutive-continua)

Comment: I think the pseudo-arc is minimal, but I don't have time to check now.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: You are correct -- in fact, the pseudo-arc is homeomorphic to each of its nontrivial subcontinua.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Thank  you  for  this  answer.

Comment: @WillBrian  I thank you too for the answer.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Since Andreas was the first to think of the pseudo-arc, I'll let him type it up as an answer if he wants to. But I looked up a reference for you if you want it: according to Wikipedia's page on the pseudo-arc, Moser first proved in 1948 that it is homeomorphic to each of its nontrivial subcontinua (the full reference is given there).

Comment: @WillBrian  Many  thanks  for  your  comments  and  reference to Moser  proof. I will accept  and upvote, with pleasure, the  answer by Andreas  or  you.

Comment: I'll let Will make it an answer, since he's the one who actually knew the fact (as opposed to my just having an opinion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Andreas points out in the comments, [the pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) provides an example of a continuum like this. This fact was first proved by Moise in 1948, in

> Edwin Moise, "An indecomposable plane continuum which is homeomorphic to each of its nondegenerate subcontinua," *Transactions of the AMS* **63** (1948), pp. 581-594.

Answer (score 5):

The term that's usually used is *hereditarily equivalent*.

As Will Brian pointed out, the pseudo-arc has this property.  It is *indecomposable*, i.e., it is not the union of two of its proper subcontinua. G. W. Henderson showed that a hereditarily equivalent *decomposable* continuum
is an arc (homeomorphic to $[0,1]$).

It is still a big open question as to whether the arc and the pseudo-arc are the only hereditarily equivalent metric continua.

**Edit July 2020:** The problem alluded to above has been solved for planar continua. The pseudo-arc is the only "minimal" (i.e. hereditarily equivalent) plane continuum other than the arc: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2020.107131.